# Finding certain highest value in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to find certain highest value in an array(for example fifth highest value).

I wrote an alogithm but it takes too long. Any ideas how to make it faster?

```
    int tab[100];
    // cin tab;

    int position;
    cin>>position;
    //  for example i need to find fifth highest
    // value in an array.

    int temp=0;

    sort( tab, tab + 100, greater <int>() );

    for(int y=0; y<100; ++y)
    {
        if (tab[y]==tab[y+1])
            continue;
        else
        {
            temp++;
            if(temp==position)
                cout<<tab[y];
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) may speed it up considerably.

Comment: And because you called sort after your input, you are timing sort + your algorithm.

Comment: You have UB when all elements are identical (`y+1` is out of bound).

Comment: You may `break` once you found the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone have mentioned in the comments using std:nth_element is a way to go if you don't want to write the algorithm yourself.

If you want to write it on your own you may want to look at this post:

[Nth largest element in a binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612362/nth-largest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree)

It explains how to find the nth element in the binary search tree.

The information what the binary search tree is can be found on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

This should give you a good starting point.

Comment: OP seems to manage duplicate values, so usage of `std::nth_element` is not so trivial.