# Finding the smallest element in a binary search tree (Iterative & Recursive)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is my implementation of finding the smallest search key in a BST using two different ways and I'd like to make sure if I'm doing it correctly:

***Iterative***

```
public T findSmallest ( BinarySearchTree<T> tree )

{ BinaryNode Node = new BinaryNode (tree.getDataRoot);

  if ( Node == null ) return null;

  while(Node.hasLeftChild()) Node = Node.getLeftChild;

return Node.getData(); }
```

***Recursively***

```
public T findSmallest ( BinaryNode Node ) 

{ if (Node == null) return null;

  if(Node.getLeftChild()==null) return Node.getData(); 

  else 

  return findSmallest ( (Node.getLeftChild()) ; }
```

Comment: If you want to know if you're right, why don't you run a test?

Comment: Aside from syntax errors, naming conventions and code formatting, everything should be ok

Comment: What do your unit tests say? Do they pass? Please respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: You may prefer to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is a site for answering specific programming questions, but not for reviewing implementations or discussing code quality. I have voted to close this question.

Comment: thank you Duncan will ask there too now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good, i reformatted the code a bit, hope i did not miss anything.

**Iterative**

```
public T FindSmallest(BinarySearchTree<T> tree){ 
  BinaryNode Node = new BinaryNode(tree.getDataRoot());
  if (Node == null) 
    return null;

  while(Node.hasLeftChild()) 
    Node = Node.getLeftChild();

  return Node.getData(); 
}
```

**Recursive**

```
public T FindSmallest(BinaryNode Node){ 
  if (Node == null) 
    return null;

  if(Node.getLeftChild()==null) 
    return Node.getData(); 

  return findSmallest(Node.getLeftChild()); 
}
```

This may interest you: [Find kth smallest element in a binary search tree in Optimum way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way)

Comment: @Sara: I hope this is not your actual code, because (due to syntax errors) it won't compile.

Comment: @TwoMore Both methods won't compile as is. In the first, it has the wrong return type, the second one also, and the second one is missing a pair of brackets in the last line...

Comment: Thank You to you too @jlordo i will modify if right now