# printing largest n values in binary search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a method to print out the largest n values in a binary search tree. I was considering altering a reverse order print method to achieve this.

reverse order print method:

```
public static void reverseOrderPrint(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) return;
    reverseOrderPrint(node.right);
    System.out.println(node.data);
    reverseOrderPrint(node.right);
}
```

I wanted to modify the method above to something like this to achieve my goals

```
// print BST reverse Order
public static void reverseOrder(TreeNode node, int n) {
    if (sizeOfBinaryTree(node) < n) {
        System.out.print("n is bigger than tree");
        return;
    }
    if (node == null) return;
    reverseOrder(node.right);
    System.out.print(node.data);
    reverseOrder(node.left);
}
```

I have considered storing the reverse order elements in an array and then returning the first n values but this would have a performance of O(n) and require extra memory. How can I perform the same task recursively without requiring extra memory? Also is this possible to complete this problem in O(log n)? or does it have to be O(n)?

Comment: Sounds cool; do you have a question?

Comment: The method you have given would print the largest n elements in the tree, there is no need to reverse order elements in array.

Comment: @codelion the method i provided prints the whole tree from largest to smallest. I wanted to use that method I have as leverage or as a hint

Comment: @Liondancer you can just stop the recursion after n elements, see my answer below.

Comment: @codelion your solution doesnt quite work =/

Comment: @Liondancer Updated the solution again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your method to below and it will print the largest n values. You can move the test for n bigger than tree outside the method. Call initially with i=0;

```
// print BST reverse Order
public static void reverseOrder(TreeNode node, int n,int i) {
    if (node == null) return;
        reverseOrder(node.right,n,i);
        if(++i<n) System.out.print(node.data);
        reverseOrder(node.left,n,i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use [Order Statistics on a Binary Search Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way), you can get the kth smallest element in O(logn)

Once you know  which element is in the 'kth ' position, you can use normal Inorder Traversal, and print all elements greater than that number. So, this would avoid the extra O(n)  storage.