# java binary search tree finding second smallest node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to make the method find the second smallest node
However, when I found the smallest node(which doesn't have right node) 
I should return the parent of the node to make it "second" smallest. However, I don't have an idea to make it like that... please help me out guys

```
public StringNode secondSmallest() {
    return secondSmallest(root);
}

private StringNode secondSmallest(StringNode x) {
    if(x==null);
    //base case: if the left node is null -> smallest
    if (x.getLeft()==null) {        
        //if there is only right child
        if(x.getRight()!=null) {
            return x.getRight();
        }
        //when there is no right node and smallest
        return x;
    }
    //keep finding left node
    else
        return secondSmallest(x.getLeft());

}
```

Comment: Your version traverses all the way down the left side, and then returns an element no matter what. This doesn't work because it doesn't follow the invariants of a BST. Are you familiar with [in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am currently learning about BST in my school. Can you explain little about it? If you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code.

```
public interface Tree<K, V> {
       /**
     * Find the nth smallest element in the tree
     * 
     * @param nth
     * @return nth smallest element in the tree
     */
    public K findSmallest(int nth);
}

@Override


 public K findSmallest(int nth) {
    Node iterator = root;
    return traverseLeftParentRight(iterator, new AtomicInteger(nth));
  }



private K traverseLeftParentRight(Node iterator, AtomicInteger nth) {
    if (null == iterator || nth.get() == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    K value = traverseLeftParentRight(iterator.left, nth);
    // Found in the left subtree itself
    if (null != value) {
      return value;
    }
    if (nth.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
      return iterator.key;
    }
    // Check in the right subtree
    return traverseLeftParentRight(iterator.right, nth);
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Create a BST
      Comparator comparator = integerComparator();
      Tree tree = new BinarySearchTree(comparator);
      fillData(tree);
      System.out.println("4thlest element " + tree.findSmallest(4));
   }

private static void fillData(Treetree) {
  tree.put(5, "value-5");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   tree.put(i, "value-" + i);
  }
 }
```

Read this [Nth Samllest Element](https://programming4interviews.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/find-n-th-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree/) article for complete details.

Comment: Found one more solution in SE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way/2329236#2329236

Comment: I think this isn't what I am looking for, I like to make a method only take one parameter "(Node x)" and use recursive way to find out the second left minimum value.  `if (nth.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
      return iterator.key;
    }` I don't get it this part too

Comment: Look at "Amazon I'm coming" solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way/2329236#2329236. You have to pass 2nd parameter too to know Nth smallest element. Pass N as 2 to get second smallest

Comment: the integer should be AtomicInteger? or It can be regular integer?

Comment: you will pass normal integer. This integer is converted to AtomicInteger in public K findSmallest(int nth) {
    Node iterator = root;
    return traverseLeftParentRight(iterator, new AtomicInteger(nth));
  }

Comment: Did you get any error with this code? Share your issues.

Comment: not yet, I think it's really good though.. sorry for late check as the answer.