# Datastructure for many queries of getting kth largest value

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to solve probelm which states: make data structure which supports:

1) Add element with key k

2) Delete element with key k

3) Print kth largest element in data structure

I thought that maxheap should work, but in this case we need to delete first k-1 largest value from heap to get the kth maximum element, so it won't work here.

How I can solve this ?

Comment: You probably want a (balanced) binary search tree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way/2329236#2329236

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find kth smallest element in a binary search tree in Optimum way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), which is a (balanced) binary tree that lets you find the ith smallest (or largest) element in log(n) time with a balanced tree.